# Scrapy follow link as well as encoding error

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been trying to implement a parse function.

Essentially I figured out through the scrapy shell that

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="PagerAfter"]/a[last()]/@href')).extract()[0]
```

gives me the url directing me to the next page. So I tried following the instructions with next_page. I took a look around stack overflow and it seems that everyone uses rule(LinkExtractor... which I don't believe I need to use. I'm pretty sure I'm doing it completely wrong though. I originally had a for loop that added every link I wanted to visit in the start_urls because I knew it was all in the form of *p1.html, *p2.html .. etc. but I want to make this smarter.

```
 def parse(self, response):
    items = []

    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="Message"]'):
        itemx = mydata()
        itemx['information'] = sel.extract()
        items.append(itemx)
        with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('\ninformation: ' + itemx.get('information')

    #URL of next page response.xpath('//*[@id="PagerAfter"]/a[last()]/@href').extract()[0]

    next_page = (response.xpath('//*[@id="PagerAfter"]/a[last()]/@href'))

    if (response.url != response.xpath('//*[@id="PagerAfter"]/a[last()]/@href')):
        if next_page:
            yield Request(response.xpath('//*[@id="PagerAfter"]/a[last()]/@href')[0], self.parse)


    return items
```

but does not work I get a

```
    next_page = (response.xpath('//*[@id="PagerAfter"]/a[last()]/@href'))
        ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

error. Additionally I know that the yield Request part is wrong. I want to recursively call and recursively add each scrape of each page into the list items.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Sorry, it is confusing. I am mostly trying to follow a link. On every page I have figured out that there is a "next" button. The next button takes you to link (response.xpath('//*[@id="PagerAfter"]/a[last()]/@href').extract()[0]. I figured this out through the scrapy shell. My main issue is I have no idea how to follow this link so that all the pages of the site is scraped.

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis here causes the syntax error: `f.write('\ninformation: ' + itemx.get('information')`

Comment: Use `next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="PagerAfter"]/a[last()]/@href').extract_first()` to return just the URL.